# Calculating Laurent expansions using geometric series in regions defined by inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality, laurent-series

So I am a bit confused about Laurent series and their relation to geometric series. I will give an example but my doubts are more general. The function:
$$f(z) = {\frac {{{\rm e}^{z}}}{
 \left( z-1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
has a singularity at $z = 1$. I know that the function converges to a Laurent series only in the region $ \left| z-1 \right| > 0$ which is an "infinite circle" centered at 1 (right?). So relating to the geometric series:
$ \left( z-1 \right) ^{-2}$ which is obtained by differentiating $ \left( 1-z \right) ^{-1}$. However, this geometric series is only valid for $$ \left| z \right| <1$$  inside the circle with radius $ \left| z \right|=1$ which is not the same as $ \left| z-1 \right| > 0$.

My question is: how can I relate a geometric series with a correct Laurent expansion and find the correct geometric series in "the correct" regions defined by a certain inequality?

Comment: Couple things: The region $|z-1| > 0$ is the region $z\ne 1$, it's the punctured plane. Second thing, what is an infinite circle? Also yes, you can find Taylor series for the function by centering the Taylor series around 0 as you're suggesting, and yes it's only valid in a circle with radius the distance to the nearest singularity. Also you simultaneously said the geometric series is and is not valid inside the circle $|z|=1$. The Laurent series is nicer because it's globally valid.

Comment: $\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$ for $|z|<1$. Then replacing $z$ with $z-1$: $\frac1{1-(z-1)}=1+(z-1)+(z-1)^2+\cdots$, valid for $|z-1|<1$.

Comment: @user170231 yes but that is not valid for $\left| z-1 \right| > 0$

Comment: @jgon by infinite circle I mean the entire plane (excluding the singularity).

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2}&=e\frac{e^{z-1}}{(z-1)^2}\\&=e\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}}{(z-1)^2}.\end{align}

Comment: Yes that is a more "clever" way of doing this however I was more interested in using the "geometric series" approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: $e^z = e\cdot e^{z-1}$  where $|z - 1| > 0$.